# How to jump/display the column of an error

Tags: python, vim, syntax, pylint, syntastic

To check the syntax of my python scripts I am using the syntastic vim plugin with pylint as checker.

Is there a way to not only display or highlight the line where an error occurs but the column/exact position of this error too?

I used a vim syntax checker plugin in the past which shows me an error while typing. So I knew exactly where an error occurs. Now I'm an old man and can't remember of this plugin... ;-(

Comment: You can use the location window and/or `:ln`/`:lp` (and other related commands) to jump to the exact position of the error.

Comment: :ln / :lp only jumps to the line but not to the exact place within that line

Comment: No, `:ln` and `:lp` jump to the right column if that information is available. They would be close to useless if they wouldn't.

Comment: @romainl I believe the proper abbreviation for `:lnext` is `:lne` (`:ln` stands for `:lnoremap`).  Anyway, a better alternative is to use Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), which provides mappings `[L`, `[l`, `]l`, and `]L` for navigating through loclists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntastic stores the errors in the *location list window*. You can use `:lopen` to show it, and then use commands like `:ll` (or `<Enter>`) to jump to the error under the cursor. Alternatively, you can also navigate through errors via `:lnext` and related commands.

If the corresponding error message did come with a column (i.e. the error looks like `filename|42 col 7| error message`), the cursor will be positioned there.

#### pylint and error columns

Syntastic gets the information from external checkers, `pylint` in your case. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350393/how-can-i-retrieve-column-offsets-for-pylint-messages), pylint currently did not support reporting of columns, only lines (but you could try out the patch mentioned in the answer).

But with recent versions of both pylint **and** Syntastic, this should work out-of-the-box!

Comment: _... the cursor will be positioned there._
This is exactly what I search for. How can I become a error message with these informations? syntastic only know the line but not the column of an error...

Comment: Syntastic gets the information from external checkers, `pylint` in your case. Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350393/how-can-i-retrieve-column-offsets-for-pylint-messages), pylint currently does not support reporting of columns, only lines (but you could try out the patch mentioned in the answer).

Comment: In the meantime `pylint` reports columns too. If I run `pylint --msg-template='{line},{column}...'` I become an output like `104,11...` but syntastic ignores this. Is there a way to pass the column values to syntastic?

Comment: Ok... :-( I'm embarrassed! With the new syntastic version it works like expected!

Comment: Based on [this code](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/python/pylint.vim#L52), it seems to be hard coded. But, (at least in the latest Syntastic code), the `{column}` config is there! Maybe you just need to upgrade Syntastic?

Comment: Well, you learned something (to check latest versions first) :-) Please conclude this question and accept my (edited) answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!